# Angular 14 cache bursting issue

Tags: angular, caching, browser-cache, angular14

I am using angular 14. I am facing some issue with cache bursting. I am using Azure to deploy my latest changes, after deploying users are seeing the older version of the app and they have to do a hard refresh to get the latest changes.

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "lr-black",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=production --output-hashing=all",
    "build:qa": "ng build --configuration=qa --output-hashing=all",
    "build:dev": "ng build --configuration=dev --output-hashing=all",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.6.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^14.2.7",
    "@angular/material": "^14.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^14.1.0",
    "@danielmoncada/angular-datetime-picker": "^14.2.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^9.0.2",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^14.3.1",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^14.3.1",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^14.3.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^14.3.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^14.3.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@types/facebook-js-sdk": "^3.3.6",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^28.2.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^28.2.0",
    "angular-google-charts": "^2.2.3",
    "angular-idle-preload": "^3.0.0",
    "angular2-notifications": "^12.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "chart.js": "^4.1.1",
    "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^2.1.0",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "firebase": "^9.16.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.18",
    "lottie-web": "^5.9.6",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^4.1.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^9.0.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^4.0.0",
    "ngx-drag-scroll": "^14.0.1",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^14.0.1",
    "ngx-lottie": "^9.1.0",
    "ngx-mat-intl-tel-input": "^5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.2.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2",
    "webpack": "^5.79.0"
  }
}
```

I tried using `--output-hashing=all` while taking build and it still didnt fix it

Angular.json

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ta-black": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ta-black",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles/styles.scss",
              "src/assets/icons/testApp.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/js/init.js",
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
              "node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ],
            "serviceWorker": true,
            "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "10mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "qa": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "5mb",
                  "maximumError": "10mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "5mb",
                  "maximumError": "10mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ta-black:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "ta-black:build:development"
            },
              "qa": {
                "browserTarget": "ta-black:build:qa"
              },
              "dev": {
                "browserTarget": "ta-black:build:dev"
              }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ta-black:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating the angular.json config file? The relevant option would be in this path

```json
{
    "targets": {
        "build": {
            "configurations": {
                "production": {
                    "outputHashing": "all"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have "outputHashing": "all" added in angular.json I have also added the file in the post can you please help me figure out what is wrong